# How to know if MouseWheelListener can receive events?

Tags: java, swing, listener, mousewheel, mouselistener

There is one `JPanel` with attached `MouseWheelListener`. This panel has on top several other JPanels, and completely occupies parent `JPanel` area. I want to know if `MouseWheelListener` can receive events when the mouse is over this parent `JPanel`. If I attach `MouseListener` to parent `JPanel` - it is not receiving any events, because on top of it there are several other JPanels.

Maybe there is some method to find out when `MouseWheelListener` can receive events? I mean like if you standing on `JScrollPane` - only then you can move the scrollbar (and it is not important how many JPanels on it).

EDIT:

The `AWTEventListener` didn't helped also - the upper JPanels still blocking parent JPanel events.. :

```
AWTEventListener awt = new AWTEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {

            if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED == e.getID()) {
                MouseEvent event = (MouseEvent) e;
                for (Component c : getComponents()) {//get all parent JPanel components
                    if (event.getComponent().equals(c)) {
                        active = true;
                        scrollBar.repaint();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED == e.getID()) {
                MouseEvent event = (MouseEvent) e;
                for (Component c : getComponents()) {
                    if (event.getComponent().equals(c)) {
                        active = false;
                        scrollBar.repaint();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(awt, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

Perhaps it is impossible to achieve that..

Comment: Generally speaking, no.  `MouseEvent`s get consumed by the higher up components.  I "think" `JScrollPane` (or more particularly) the `JViewport` attach listeners that it needs directly to the view

Comment: The problem is that I made my scrollpane from scratch, using only JComponents/JPanels, and I want to change a scrollbar appearance if it can be scrolled (mouse is over the scrollable area).

Comment: Here's a an example of the problem. If your create a panel and add a mixture of components and JScrollPanes (with, let's says JTextComponents), the inner scroll panes will consume mouse events that normally would go to the outer scrollpane. You could attach an AWTEventListener via the Toolkit and monitor for things like mouse moved, but you'd need to determine if the source is a child of your JScrollPane...

Comment: Yes, I will try to experiment with AWTEventListener. Thanks indeed.